# how best to compile gnu.mail.providers

Tags: java, api, version-control, open-source, gnu

I'm interested in forking [gnu.mail.providers.nntp.NNTPFolder](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/mail/source/gnu/mail/providers/nntp/NNTPFolder.java?root=classpathx&view=log), with the Javadoc documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/classpathx/javamail/javadoc/gnu/mail/providers/nntp/NNTPFolder.html), but don't quite understand the dependencies.  Apparently, these are:

> The current stable release of GNU JavaMail is version 1.1.2, available
>   here.
>
> You also need the current versions of GNU JAF and GNU inetlib to build
>   it.

http://www.gnu.org/software/classpathx/javamail/

What, exactly, do I need to download to build gnu.mail.providers?  I can certainly check out the code easily enough, but I don't relish compiling a large chunk of the API.  (Yes, it shouldn't be necessary to compile most classes more than once.)

1.)  What JAR's do I need to download?

2.)  How much of the source code do I need to checkout?

3.)  I can check it into github right away, because the licensing boilerplate is in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the JAR's:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnu_cvs/dist$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnu_cvs/dist$ ll lib/
total 416
drwxrwxr-x 2 thufir thufir   4096 Feb 22 21:16 ./
drwxrwxr-x 6 thufir thufir   4096 Feb 22 21:16 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir  33542 Feb 22 21:16 activation.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir 180559 Feb 22 21:16 gnumail.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir 194251 Feb 22 21:16 inetlib.jar
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnu_cvs/dist$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnu_cvs/dist$ ll
total 608
drwxrwxr-x 6 thufir thufir   4096 Feb 22 21:16 ./
drwxrwxr-x 5 thufir thufir   4096 Feb 22 21:36 ../
drwxrwxr-x 3 thufir thufir   4096 Feb 22 21:16 gnu/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir 593467 Feb 22 21:16 gnu_cvs.jar
drwxrwxr-x 3 thufir thufir   4096 Feb 22 21:16 javax/
drwxrwxr-x 2 thufir thufir   4096 Feb 22 21:16 lib/
drwxrwxr-x 2 thufir thufir   4096 Feb 22 21:16 META-INF/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir   1322 Feb 22 21:16 README.TXT
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnu_cvs/dist$
```

Whether it runs correctly remains to be seen.  I suppose it has to be build to compile as `gnumail-providers.jar` but otherwise seems, at first glance, to work fine.  I checked out the code as per:

> Alternatively you can retrieve the current sources via CVS [here](https://savannah.gnu.org/cvs/?group_id=139),
>   module mail.

http://www.gnu.org/software/classpathx/javamail/