# use reflection to modify a method and gain access to its local variables

Tags: java, api, reflection, version-control, gnu

Since I'm [not quite sure what's involved with forking gnu.mail.providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000118/how-best-to-compile-gnu-mail-providers) I'd like use reflection to interact with this class.

I think the arithmetic in [getMessage](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/mail/source/gnu/mail/providers/nntp/NNTPFolder.java?root=classpathx&view=log) is incorrect:

```
          GroupResponse gr = ns.connection.group(name);
          first = gr.first;
          last = gr.last;
          count = gr.count;
          // Get article
          m = getMessageImpl(msgnum - 1 + first);
          // Cache store
          articleCache.put(key, m);
          return m;
```

In any event, I'd like to gain access to the GroupResponse object above in the getMessage method.  While I know that reflection can do things along these lines, I'm not sure how to get this particular object from this particular method.  I've used reflection to gain access to some of the fields (first, last, count), but this seems a little different.

It's the [GroupResponse](http://developer.classpath.org/inet/doc/gnu/inet/nntp/GroupResponse.html) class which seems to hold everything together.

Can I use reflection to write a custom getMessage method and "tack" it onto NNTPFolder?  I'm not sure what's possible or advisable.

Comment: You cannot use reflection to inspect or modify the contents of existing methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [Byteman](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ABytemanTutorial#top). Using it, you can describe a rule that whenever the method `getMessage()` on the affected class is called, your own code will be called.

Comment: yeah, this looks possible.  However, the amount of work involved seems greater than forking the GNU project (perhaps).

Comment: I went ahead and forked the GNU project -- or at least modified the source for my own purposes.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use reflection to modify the contents of a method. You cannot use byte code manipulation libraries to modify the contents of a method. With byte code manipulation though, you can intercept the method call and redirect to another method of your choice. That's about as close as you are going to get afaik.

Another option would be to obtain the source of the libraries, make some modifications to suit your needs, and recompile.

Comment: With more advanced tools he could also modify the class file such that he keeps everything the same, but inserts different bytecode for that one method, which he can decompile, change, and recompile.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - yes indeed he could, though that would be approaching [Black Magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_magic).

Comment: Heh heh, then it's black magic that we needed to do on a massive scale in a serious corporate project :)